# Google picker callback not working in angular

Tags: angular, callback, picker

I am using google picker in angular but when I am going to call a function in callback. Picker shows it undefined error for that function. If anyone found any other method to call a function in callback please answer.

```
loadEditPicker() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': this.editAuthApiLoad.bind(this) });
    gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': this.editPickerApiLoad.bind(this) });
  }

  editAuthApiLoad() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': 'my-client-id',
        'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
        'immediate': false
      },
      this.updateNewDocument);
  }

  editPickerApiLoad() {
    this.pickerApiLoaded = true;
  }

  updateNewDocument(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      if (authResult.access_token) {
        let view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
          .setOAuthToken(authResult.access_token)
          .addView(view)
          .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
          .setCallback(this.myCallback())
          .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my above question. I just need to replace

```
this.updateNewDocument
```

with

```
this.updateNewDocument.bind(this)
```

while calling the function.